# Good resources concerning linking process in compilation

Tags: resources, linker, compilation, dynamic-linking

I've been coding for some time, and I always thought the linking phase of compilation was pretty straight forward, but recently I had to add a plugin system to an app, and I ran into quite a few compilation and runtime problems, due to my complete lack of knowledge on the matter. I've now got it working fine and learned a lot in the process, but now that I' aware I still have a lot to learn on the subject, I wanted to explore the subject more. So I was wondering if anyone had good pointers on articles, blog posts, or books on the whole "code sections, symbols, linking, dynamic/static libraries..." business.

I'm developing on Linux using gcc and ld, but I'm also interested in the M$ way of doing things, I thirst for knowledge :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some good online resources:

- [Static, Shared Dynamic and Loadable Linux Libraries](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)
- [Program Library HOWTO](http://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Ulrich Drepper (maintainer of glibc) provides a very thorough description of the linux implementation of shared libraries in his paper [How To Write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), definitely worth a read if you want to know the nitty-gritty details.  I actually can't think of a book that does a great job covering the details.